# UINavigationController hidesBarOnSwipe memory leak issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've got a problem with `hidesBarOnSwipe` property of `UINavigationController`.

**Overview :**

[Link to project file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/cb370984199ebc4d10ddf0d2c9b5b7da20171207115248/32faa5)

I have one controller named FirstViewController which is root view of `UINavigationController`. 
Everything is in `Main.storyboard`.
FirstViewController contains `UIButton` action. Inside that action I instantiate a SecondViewController and push it on a navigation stack.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Inside SecondViewController there is only an `hidesBarsOnSwipe` property set to `YES` on `viewDidLoad` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
}
```

and dealloc gets NSLogged :

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Dealloc");
}
```

**Problem :**

When we swipe up to hide navigationBar, dealloc is never get called. Instruments shows a SecondViewController memory leak here.

When we are on SecondViewController and we just press back button - everything is fine. Dealloc gets called.

There is definitly some kind of retain cycle but i have no idea why and how to avoid this kind of situation.

Comment: Just got the same issue. Xcode 9.2(beta)

Comment: This seems to be iOS 11+ issue. Everything working fine on iOS 10.3-

Answer (score 2):

**Some updates and temporary solution :**

There is another method to perform navigationBar hiding.
What worked for me is to use :

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:hidden animated:YES];
```

To achieve good results add a property in your class to keep track status of navigationBar animation :

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL statusBarAnimationInProgress;
```

Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` like this :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat yVelocity = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:scrollView].y;
    if (yVelocity > 0 && !self.statusBarAnimationInProgress) {
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    } else if (yVelocity < 0 && !self.statusBarAnimationInProgress) {
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Set navigation bar hidden should look like :

```
- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    [CATransaction begin];
    self.statusBarAnimationInProgress = YES;
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        self.statusBarAnimationInProgress = NO;
    }];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:hidden animated:YES];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

I use CATransaction to check if animation of navigation bar is completed. Any way that works. Not so easy solution but at least there is no leak :)